# Setup basic postgres database using Chef

Tags: postgresql, chef-infra, chef-recipe

I am trying to set up a very basic postgres database using Chef, but lack the Chef experience to make sense of the documentation I find in the supermarket's cookbook readme:
https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/postgresql

What I require is the chef equivalent of the following:

- creating a user
- creating a database owned by that user
- make a small change to pg_hba.conf so it requires a password
- start the database

I would expect to be able to google an example of something as basic as this, but currently get lost in all the possible ways of configuring postgresql that I don't find a starting point.
If another cookbook would make more sense please explain why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't currently have a great answer for making the DB user and database. The old `database` cookbook used to handle that, but the code was so unmaintainable we felt obligated to deprecate it without a replacement plan. It does still exist and should proooobably work, but it's not a Delightful experience :( For the hba config, you can control that using the `postgresql` cookbook and some node attributes and similarly that will handle starting the database service for you.

Answer (score 1):

I got help from the Gist given here: https://gist.github.com/exoer/1063712/01e9b166add182c14b54508ef5950152063f6de2 :

```
#
# Cookbook Name:: atari
# Recipe:: db_server
#
# Copyright 2010, Atari
#
# All rights reserved
#

include_recipe "postgresql::server"

r = package "ruby-pg" do
  package_name "libpgsql-ruby"
  action :nothing
end
r.run_action(:upgrade)

# Snippet from opscode to reload gems
require 'rubygems'
Gem.clear_paths
require "pg"

execute "create-database-user" do
  command "createuser -U postgres -SDRw youruser"
  only_if do
    c = PGconn.connect(:user=>'postgres', :dbname=>'postgres')
    r = c.exec("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM pg_user WHERE usename='youruser'")
    r.entries[0]['count']
  end
end

execute "create-database" do
  command "createdb -U postgres -O youruser-E utf8 -T template0 yourdb"
  only_if do
    c = PGconn.connect(:user=>'postgres', :dbname=>'postgres')
    r = c.exec("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM pg_database WHERE datname='yourdb'")
    r.entries[0]['count']
  end
end
```

Also checked postgres docs: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/app-createdb.html

Finally I edited my dev-cookbook/recipes/db.rb and **created the user** with:

```
# d - user is allowed to create database
# l - user is allowed to log in
# s - user is a superuser
execute "create-database-user" do
  command "createuser -U postgres -dls db_user"
end
```

And **the database** with:

```
# U - user that is used to connect to psql
# O - owner of the database
# E - database encoding
execute "create-database" do
  command "createdb -U postgres -O db_user db_name -E 'utf8'"
end
```